# Trying to get a c program to display this in GCC

Tags: c

How to display this on the screen in C programming?
Number of days in the month: 30 
Code for the starting day: 3

```
Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa So 
      01 02 03 04 05 
06 07 08 09 10 11 12 
13 14 15 16 17 18 19 
20 21 22 23 24 25 26 
27 28 29 30
```

I can do the first part (the numbers of days in the month:30 and code for the starting day:3)

but I'm not sure how to do the 2nd part. The problem im facing is that I cant use multiple printf due to the fact that the calendar (the 2nd part) has to be related to the number of days.

If anyone is able to lend me a hand (preferably emailing me so I can have a bit of a chat)

Thanks here is my program so far

just to note I cant use arrays + strings

```
#include <stdio.h>

int days, number, counter;

int main(){
while(true){
    printf("Enter how many days are in this month ");
    scanf("%d",&days);
    if((days>=28)&&(days<=31)){
      break;
    }else {
      printf("Invalid number of days in this month \n");
    }
  }
  while(true){
    printf("Enter the day of the week it starts I.e. 1 = Mondays. 7= Sunday ");
    scanf("%d", &number);
    if((number>=1)&&(number<=7)){
      break;
    }else {
      printf("You suck enter it again \n");
    }
  }
  printf("There are %d amount of days in this month", days);
  printf("The starting day for this month is %d", number);
  printf("Mo Tu We Thu Fri Sa So \n", Mo, Tu, We, Thu, Fri, Sa, So);
}
```

Comment: _"You suck enter it again \n"_ ; you used string.

Comment: Your question isn't concretely clear, but if I gather correctly, you're trying to figure out how to print the days in a structured way, correct?

Comment: Yeah it has to be structured in that way

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
printf("Mo\tTu\tWe\tThu\tFri\tSa\tSo\t\n");
for(i=1;i<=35;i++)
{
    if(i >= number && i<days+number)
        printf("%02d\t", i-number+1);
    else
        printf("\t");
    if(i%7==0) printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: I have edited the answer a bit for better formatting and corrected an offset. It should look good now.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't concretely clear, but if I gather correctly, you're trying to figure out how to print the days in a structured way. If so, then you can do this (without using arrays and the like):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i = 0;
    int days = 30;
    int day = 1;//this defines the number of days by which to offset printing the days

    for (i = 0; i < days + day + 1; ++i) {
        if (i > day) {
            printf("%02d ", i - day);//this outputs the number with a leading zero (so, it takes up 2 spaces)
        }
        else {
            printf("   ");//note: 3 spaces (2 for the numbers, 1 for spacing)
        }
        if (i % 7 == 0) {
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This outputs the numbers (correctly formatted):

```
   01 02 03 04 05 06
07 08 09 10 11 12 13
14 15 16 17 18 19 20
21 22 23 24 25 26 27
28 29 30
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int weekDay = 3;
    int monthDay = 30;
    int i, wd, d;
    wd = weekDay -1;
    printf("Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa So\n");
    for(i=0;i<wd;++i)
        printf("%*s", 3, "");

    for(d=1;d<=monthDay;++d){
        printf("%02d ", d);
        if(++wd == 7){
            printf("\n");
            wd = 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```